# Runtime.getRuntime().exec() execute two lines?

Tags: java, shell, runtime.exec

I need to run two lines in Runtime.getRuntime().exec(), this two:

```
cd %CMS_HOME%
ant deploy
```

Now is it possible to make a `.bat` file, but I think it is useless for two lines,
is muss be easier! Someone any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in a `.bat` file.  It's not useless; that's just how Runtime.exec works.

You should look into using the [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class instead of `Runtime.exec()`.  It was introduced in JDK 5 as the successor to `Runtime.exec()`.

Comment: I know that .bat is a good way to run the lines. But I need more commands of 2 lines. And to make for every two lines a .bat file, it would be messy.

Comment: No, I disagree.  Why "messy"?  Do it and move on.

Comment: Right, just do it and move on.  Why fret about something that has no basis?  Your "messy" concerns are groundless.

Answer (score 3):

Invoke the task [programmatically from Java](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0502_gawor/0502_gawor.html):

```
File buildFile = new File("build.xml");
Project p = new Project();
p.setUserProperty("ant.file", buildFile.getAbsolutePath());
p.init();
ProjectHelper helper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
p.addReference("ant.projectHelper", helper);
helper.parse(p, buildFile);
p.executeTarget(p.getDefaultTarget());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Runtime.exec(String command, String[] envp, File dir)` to execute `ant deploy` in a `dir` folder.

P.S. Executing ant, which is a java program, using a batch file from another java program is a little bit weird. You can run it just as a java class...

Comment: Hmm, also this isn't working for me. When I do it in cmd it works. But when I do it in Runtime.getRuntime().exec() he can't find the file..

Answer (score 2):

When you are running external application you have to behavior according to the rules of target operating system.

In your case you want to run 2 commands on windows, so you have to say:

`cd TheDir && ant`

Try it first in command line. Then to make it working run this command with prefix `cmd` from java:

`cmd /c cd TheDir && ant`

Alternatively you can use pure java solution. Use `ProcessBuilder` instead of `Runtime.exec()`. ProcessBuilder allows you to set working directory, so then you can run `ant` directly.

And the last point. Actually you do not have to run external process at all. Ant is java application. You can run its `main()`  method directly from you application and specify all needed parameters.

Comment: De method with && is working in CMD, but not working with runtime. What is a little strange if you ask me..

Comment: The version with `cmd` should probably include quotation marks: `cmd /c "cd TheDir && ant"`, otherwise it's more likely that `&&` would delimit the entire `cmd /c cd TheDir` part from `ant` than just `cd TheDir`. *EDIT:* Just tested, and yes, that's what really happens, so double quotes are necessary indeed.

Comment: But in Java I can't do this, because with the quotes it is outside of the String!