# Execute ".bat" file that contains multiple lines from Java

Tags: java, cmd, runtime.exec

I have a folder named **A** that contains a `.bat` file: **a.bat**.
If I wanted to write a `.bat` file I could write:

```
cd A/
call a.bat
```

and I would see the results, but if I want to run it from `Java` I have problems.

I'm trying to do this:

```
String command = "cmd.exe /c start cd A/\ncall a.bat";
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command); 
} catch (IOException e) { }
```

I tried to replace `\n` with `;` and with `\r` and with `&&` but that didn't work. (It doesn't recognize that there exist two lines).

How can I run multiple lines from a `.bat` from `Java`?

Comment: See this one for some good options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680968/runtime-getruntime-exec-execute-two-lines

Comment: as per a simple temporary solution , you can put these two lines in some other batch file and execute that only

Comment: I know that but the whole point of my program is to encapsulate this file. So creating a `.bat` file is not an option for me.

Comment: @MarounMaroun - check my response. See if it solves your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the working directory for the process from the Java side at the point where you spawn `cmd`, rather than needing a `cd` command:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "a.bat");
pb.directory(new File("path\\to\\A"));
Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: Is there a way to actually open the `CMD` window to see the results?

Comment: @MarounMaroun maybe by using `start`, i.e. `new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "start", "a.bat")`?  I'm not a Windows user so I don't know for sure.